# Android Huawei Ascend Y300 invalid int: ""

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

i am developing an simple Android App.
When I'm starting the App in the emulator, everything is fine and works normally. In an activity I'm showing data within an GridView and each view has also an Dialog.

But when I'm trying to start the App on my Huawei Ascend Y300 smartphone, the LogCat is saying "invalid int: "" " and there will be display nothing.

Ironically, the main activity has the same error, but informations of the main activity is not selected from database.

Whats my fault? Can you guys help me?

Thank you so much!!

EDIT: The codeline where the exception occures is not written from me. The LogCat is shown something like this:

`10-21 19:18:29.570: W/System.err(2330): Invalid int: ""`

Comment: `Whats my fault?` You are trying to parse "" or " " as an interger. Neither "" nor " " is an integer. It's not a number at all. Replace it with "0".

Comment: thank you for your answer!! I wanted to post a picture of the LogCat but it was denied..
The LogCat is not saying in which class or line this exception occures..
And i'm sure that is not my code!

Comment: It should say: "This issue occurred in this class, at this line"... WILD GUESS: you are trying to process the input from an EditText

Comment: Im selecting from database, no edittext

Comment: But you are trying to convert an empty string to an integer. So, you better avoid the conversion if the trimmed string is null or empty (empty != null).

Comment: But why does the emulator not printing an message like this? Is the SQLite database also on the device when I am running the app?

Comment: `Is the SQLite database also on the device when I am running the app?` If you create it at run time, yes, it's there. Sory, but **I must see some code** to tell what's happening.

Comment: No, I i have created the database with an other application on my macbook.. 
could this be the problem? 

About source code: i have no idea where the exception occures, so i dont know which code i should post..

Comment: At least, did you put the db in your `assets` folder and then copy it into the expected destination path?

Comment: Nope :(
i thought android does that for me :(

Comment: So, you need a prior understanding of all the story goes. Android expects the db to be in a certain folder (each app has its own private folder), in order to use it. You either create it there or copy it there if not existing (usually from the assets folder)